# How can I capture the value of ConsumerRecord when there is a deserialization exception?

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm using spring boot 2.1.7.RELEASE and spring-kafka 2.2.8.RELEASE.And I'm using @KafkaListener annotation to create a consumer and I'm using all default settings for the consumer.

I've extended SeekToCurrentErrorHandler and overriding handle method as shown below. Now my question is, I'm getting null for the value instead of the actual value since it's not able to deserialize the value. In this case, If I want to DLT the ConsumerRecord with key and value, Is it possible?

```
  @Override
  public void handle(Exception thrownException, List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> data,
      Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container) {

if(thrownException instanceof DeserializationException){
  final String messageKey = (String) data.get(0).key();

 logger.logException(thrownException, "DeserializerException occurred for  message key"+messageKey, getClass());

  System.out.println("messageKey is "+messageKey);
  System.out.println("Value is "+data.get(0).value());

  List<Object> list =  Arrays.stream(data.get(0).headers().toArray()).filter( header -> {
    return header.key().contains("springDeserializerExceptionValue");
  }).collect(Collectors.toList());


  //TODO: Identify how do we DLT the message if we don't get the value in the consumer record
} else
  //Calling super method to let the 'SeekToCurrentErrorHandler' do what it is actually designed for
  super.handle(thrownException, data, consumer, container);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The failed value is in the exception - getData().